# How to pass data between stack navigator and drawer navigator in react native

Tags: react-native

Here is my navigator part of my app.

```
const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
  Home: { screen: Stack},
    History: { screen: History},
    Transactions: { screen: Transactions},
  Profile:{screen:EditProfile},
  Wallet:{screen:Wallet},
  ResetPassword:{screen:ResetPassword},

  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <Drawer {...props} />
  },
  {
        contentOptions: {
              activeTintColor: '#e91e63',

            }
  }

);


const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: Splash },
  Login: { screen: Login},
  Register: { screen: Register},
  ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword},
  CreateProfile: { screen: CreateProfile},
  UploadDocuments: { screen: UploadDocuments},
  Home: {screen: drawerNavigator},


}, {
     headerMode: 'none',
     initialRouteName: 'Splash'

})
```

Currently when in stack navigator if successfully registered then i send to Home screen which is drawer navigator.In drawer navigator i made a custom drawer which has a header which has two field name and age.So in stack navigator i send that data like this.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Home",{result,result})
```

and the result data contains the name and age in it.
But in drawer i cant recieve data why? I am using react navigation 3 here.
Code for my drawer is.

```
componentDidMount(){
    var result =this.props.navigation.getParam('result');
    this.setState({name:result['name'],profession:result['profession']})
}




render() {
      return (
                <View style={{flex:1}}>



                <View style={{height:'36%', backgroundColor:'#8D6CFD', justifyContent:'center',marginBottom:10,paddingBottom:-20}}>
                    <StarRating

                    containerStyle={{marginRight:20,width:'40%',alignSelf:'flex-end',marginTop:-20,marginBottom:10}}
                    disabled={false}
                    emptyStar={'ios-star-outline'}
                    fullStar={'ios-star'}
                    fullStarColor='#F0E68C'
                    emptyStarColor='black'
                    halfStarColor='#F0E68C'
                    halfStar={'ios-star-half'}
                    iconSet={'Ionicons'}
                    starSize={25}
                    maxStars={5}
                    rating={this.state.starCount}
                    selectedStar={(rating) => this.onStarRatingPress(rating)}
                    />
                    <View style ={{flexDirection:'row',marginLeft:20,alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <Image source={require('../assets/doctor/doctor1.jpg')}  style={{height:70, width:70,borderRadius:70/2}} />
                            <View style={{marginLeft:10}}>
                                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>{this.state.name}</Text>
                                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>{this.state.age}</Text>
                            </View>
                    </View>
                </View>









                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("History")}>
                                <View style={styles.drawerlayout}>
                                 <Image source={require('../assets/nav/history.png')} style={styles.drawerimage} />
                     <Text style={styles.drawertext}>History</Text>
                                </View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>




                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Transactions")}>
                                <View style={styles.drawerlayout}>
                                 <Image source={require('../assets/nav/notification.png')} style={styles.drawerimage} />
                     <Text style={styles.drawertext}>Transactions</Text>
                                </View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>






                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                            AsyncStorage.removeItem('uname', (err) => {

                            ToastAndroid.show("Successfully logged out", ToastAndroid.LONG);
                            this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")
                            });
                    }}>
                                <View style={styles.drawerlayout}>
                                 <Image source={require('../assets/nav/logout.png')} style={styles.drawerimage} />
                     <Text style={styles.drawertext}>Logout</Text>
                                </View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>



                                </View>

  );


 }
```

above code gives me error that result['name'] is undefined.

Comment: `this.props.navigation.navigate("Home",{result,result})` this should be `this.props.navigation.navigate("Home",{result: result})` with a colon rather than a comma. You also have two screens called Home in your navigation.

Answer (score 0):

in constructor defining initial state worked for me

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setState({name:'',profession:''})
    }
```

then in componentDidMount do

```
var result =this.props.navigation.getParam('result');
    this.setState({name:result['name'],profession:result['profession']})
```